# Show first paragraph then click to show rest

Tags: jquery

I need to to able to show the first paragraph in each col then on click Find out more to show the other paragraph(s) of that col.

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h2>About Us</h2>
              <img src="images/aboutus.jpg">
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <div class="sub-content-btn">Find out more</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <h2>About Us</h2>
              <img src="images/aboutus.jpg">
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <div class="sub-content-btn">Find out more</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <h2>About Us</h2>
              <img src="images/aboutus.jpg">
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
              <div class="sub-content-btn">Find out more</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is the jQuery used so far:

```
$('.col').each(function() { 
    $(this).find('p:not(:first)').hide();
  });

  $('.sub-content-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.col').find('p').show();
  });
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div.col').each(function() {
    $(this).find('p:eq(0)').show();
});

$('.sub-content-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev('p').show();
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/baGSF/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this, using the visibility property in CSS to hide your additional paragraphs, and using the show() and hide() functions in JS to change this property. I provided a sample callback... you'd have to put it in an event handler like a button click or something.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    p.more {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// on click...
function some_callback(e) {
    $('p.more').show();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<p class="first">first paragraph is visible</p>
<p class="more">this paragraph is hidden</p>
<p class="more">you have to click to see these other paragraphs</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (leaves your current markup intact) -

```
$('.sub-content-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.col').find('p:nth-child(4)').toggle();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/CXkqn/

Based on adding the "more" class to the extra paragraphs -

```
$('.sub-content-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.col').find('.more').toggle();
})
```

Comment: What happens if there are more than 1 extra paragraph per col?

Comment: You didn't say that or ask that in your original post. Are you asking us to solve for something we cannot see or anticipate?

Comment: Sorry I;ve edited the post now, can u help?

Comment: The answer that @ktm5124 is the one that you want. Add classes to the extra paragraphs and toggle those classes.

Comment: It's going to be dynamic content. At the moment it shows the paragraphs but doesn't hide them again.

Comment: Use toggle() instead of show(). I just edited my answer to reflect adding a class of 'more' to the paragraphs that follow the first one.